# Magento 2 : Page access by customer group

Tags: magento2

We want create one page like info, and then the page just can access for staff only. The staff from customer group. How to do it, please help me. Thanks

Comment: you can do it using event and observer when user logins then you need to check the customer group by taking customer id from the session and then if the id matches you desired customer group then put a check over there either to display or not

Comment: @Chikku You have code or something can I follow it?

Comment: i have worked on certain critera where we have hide price and cart button based on customer group and i have done that with the help of event and observer this is also a similar case the concept of event and observer can be used here as well

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:-

**RestrictAccess.php** this is your observer

```
class RestrictAccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_urlInterface;
    protected $_urlFactory;
    protected $_context;
    protected $_actionFlag;
    protected $_messageManagaer;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_helper;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Helper $helper
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->_context = $context;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        if(!$this->_helper->isEnabled($storeId)) {
            return;
        }
        
        $isCustomerLoggedIn = $this->_context->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        if($isCustomerLoggedIn) {
            return;
        }
        
        $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        $actionFullName = strtolower($request->getFullActionName());
        if($actionFullName === 'cms_noroute_index') {
            $noroutePage = $this->_helper->getNoroutePage($storeId);
            if(!$this->_helper->canAccessCmsPage($noroutePage, $storeId)) {
                return $this->_restrictAccessRedirect($this->_helper->getConfigData("cms", "message", $storeId));
            }
        } else if($actionFullName === 'cms_index_index') {
            if(!$this->_helper->canAccessHomepage($storeId)) {
                return $this->_restrictAccessRedirect($this->_helper->getConfigData("cms", "message", $storeId));
            }
        } else if($actionFullName === 'cms_page_view') {
            $pageId = $request->getParam('page_id', false);
            if($pageId && !$this->_helper->canAccessCmsPageId($pageId, $storeId)) {
                return $this->_restrictAccessRedirect($this->_helper->getConfigData("cms", "message", $storeId));
            }
        } else {
            $restrictRoutes = [];
            if($customRoutes = $this->_helper->getCustomRoutes($storeId)) {
                foreach($customRoutes as $customRoute) {
                    $restrictRoutes[] = $customRoute['value'];
                }
                if (in_array($actionFullName, $restrictRoutes)) {
                    return $this->_restrictAccessRedirect($this->_helper->getConfigData("custom", "message", $storeId));
                }
            }

            $restrictRoutes = [];
            if(!$this->_helper->canAccessCategory($storeId)) {
                $restrictRoutes[] = 'catalog_category_view';
                $restrictRoutes[] = 'catalog_category_index';
            }

            if(!$this->_helper->canAccessProduct($storeId)) {
                $restrictRoutes[] = 'catalog_product_view';
            }

            if(!$this->_helper->canAccessSearch($storeId)) {
                $restrictRoutes[] = 'catalogsearch_result_index';
            }

            if (in_array($actionFullName, $restrictRoutes)) {
                return $this->_restrictAccessRedirect($this->_helper->getConfigData("catalog", "message", $storeId));
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _restrictAccessRedirect($message) {
        $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
        $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->_customerSession->authenticate();
        return;
    }
}
```

**Events.xml**

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
            <observer name="restrict_access" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RestrictAccess" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

Comment: Where file you insert the code, and how to use it. Sorry I still new in Magento 2.

Comment: you need to create a custom module and then you can use this code if you dont know how to create a custom module then you can follow this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/